# My process are stopping on sql server. I'm trying to run a procedure and using codeigniter 3

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, procedure

I don't know why, when I try to call a procedure in my application, my process are stopping on SQL Server and my page stay waiting forever.
I tryed to run the same query on SQL Server Management Studio and I had sucess, but in my application not too much.

My Controller: test.php

```
 class Test extends CI_Controller 
 {

   public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function index()
   {
      $this->load->model('test_model');
      $data['test'] = $this->test_model->get_test();
   }
 }
```

My model: test_model.php

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model 
{

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function get_test(){
    $query = "Myproc 'param1', 'param2', 'param3'";
    $rs = $this->db->query($query)->result_array(); //code stop here
    print_r($rs); 
    die();
  }
}
```

Comment: Query is invalid.

Comment: please update your question, because $query = "Myproc 'param1', 'param2', 'param3'"; doesn't make any sense at all

Comment: When I tried this query on SQL Server Management Studio it worked normally

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter, I skipped the ORM and call SQL Server store procedures using PDO.

```
// This is the Model

class Xm_system_model extends CI_Model {

  protected $pdo;

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

  // variables dsn, db_username, and db_password are stored in a config file 
  // that's autoloaded.

      $this->pdo = new PDO($this->config->item('dsn'), $this->config->item('db_username'), $this->config->item('db_password'));

  }


// This is a function that calls a sproc using two string parameters.

// (Notice the appalling lack of user input validating
// and error catching. IKR?)

public function get_screens($xlogin = '', $xsystem = '') {

$result = array();

  $sql = "exec xs_GetScreens ?, ?";

  $param1 = $xlogin;
  $param2 = $xsystem;

  $ds = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

  $ds->bindParam(1, $param1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $ds->bindParam(2, $param2, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $ds->execute();

  $result = $ds->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

  return $result;
  }
}
```

Calling from controller...

```
public function screens() {

  $this->load->model('xm_system_model');

  $this->view_data['screen_list'] = $this->xm_system_model->get_screens($xlogin, $xsystem);

   $this->load->view("some_view_name", $this->view_data);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but only return me a empty array and I run the same query on my SQL Server Management Studio and it worked and return me a lot rows. Before that I tested the connection with a simple select and I had sucess using pdo connection.

Answer (score 0):

I put this code in and it worked
**SET NOCOUNT ON;**

```
public function get_screens($xlogin = '', $xsystem = '') {

  $result = array();

  $sql = "
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  exec xs_GetScreens ?, ?
  ";

  $param1 = $xlogin;
  $param2 = $xsystem;

  $ds = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

  $ds->bindParam(1, $param1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $ds->bindParam(2, $param2, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $ds->execute();

  $result = $ds->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

  return $result;
  }
}
```